# Alternatives to MKLocalSearch?

Tags: ios, core-location, mklocalsearch

I am trying to add Check In functionality to my app much in the way that FourSquare and Yelp have.

I've implemented `CoreLocation` and am able to reverse geocode the users address, but I would like to present the names of the establishments in the users location and have them select the Bar/Restaurant they are in.

I've just implemented MKLocalSearch and find that the list bars is dismally incomplete, so I can't proceed with this as a solution.  Can anyone provide alternatives to `MKLocalSearch` and perhaps advise on pros and cons that I will encounter?

Comment: Try Google Places API https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/

Comment: Hey Shahrukh, thanks for this.  For my purposes, this looks incredibly promising.  Cheers!